# как растянуть див

Tags: html, css

у меня есть див в который пишется информаци, проблема в том, что когда её много - то на идет в строчку и уходит за границы, как сделать чтобы она не шла в строчку а переносилась на следующие строчки, а сам див бы растягивался?
есть нюанс в том, что чтобы выравнить этот див справа я использую float: right, а поэтом он как бы находится сверху дива и не растягивает его а накладывается на следующее поле, соответственно нужно либо знать как по-другому выравнивать элемент по правому краю, как при том варианте что я исползую переноситть контент на другую строчку

Comment: А зачем тебе увеличивать `div`, если можно сразу сделать его подходящего размера. Не совсем понятно какая информация, то есть информация вводимая пользователем или нет. Какой-то очень глупый и не понятный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Float устарел, попробуй переверстать с флексами ну или на гридах. Ну а с дивом, установи ширину, а высоту не трогай, параграфу установи 100% ширину

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендовано использовать `display: flex;` или `display: grid;`
Для их быстрого и простого изучения используйте https://flexboxfroggy.com/ или https://cssgridgarden.com/